# Prove that $\sum_{i=0}^{jk}{jk\choose i}=\left[\sum_{i=0}^{j}{j\choose i} \right]^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove that,

(1)

$$\sum_{i=0}^{jk}{jk\choose i}=\left[\sum_{i=0}^{j}{j\choose i} \right]^k=\left[\sum_{i=0}^{k}{k\choose i} \right]^j$$

I can't find something similar hints from mathword (binomial coefficients) to tackle (1)

Can anybody help please?

---

$$\sum_{i=0}^{8}{8\choose i}=\left[\sum_{i=0}^{4}{4\choose i} \right]^2=\left[\sum_{i=0}^{2}{2\choose i} \right]^4$$

$1+8+28+56+70+56+28+8+1=(1+4+6+4+1)^2=(1+2+1)^4$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that  $$\sum_{i=0}^{j}{j\choose i}= \sum_{i=0}^{j}{j\choose i} 1^i1^{j-i}=(1+1)^j=2^j $$

From the binomial theorem. Note $$2^{kj}=\left( 2^j \right)^k$$ Our proof is done.

Comment: As simple as that. +1